# Use same value from a random result

Tags: java, minecraft

Currently my code gets all the values from my config in a certain section, then I have something else that randomly chooses from the list. I get the random result via `getRandomStringFromList(getLocationList())`. So, I use it like this,

```
p.teleport(new Location(Bukkit.getWorld("world"), 
    plugin.getConfig().getInt("locations." + plugin.getRandomStringFromList(plugin.getLocationList()) + ".x"), 
    plugin.getConfig().getInt("locations." + plugin.getRandomStringFromList(plugin.getLocationList()) + ".y"), 
    plugin.getConfig().getInt("locations." + plugin.getRandomStringFromList(plugin.getLocationList()) + ".z"))
);
```

However, this has some problems. Instead of using the same result, it gets a different random one for all 3. I need them all to use the result in the third, how would I do this?

Comment: You could start by not doing that in a one line code (a mess to debug). This would let you store the random value in a tmp variable to reuse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the random String in a local variable and use that in the `p.teleport`. Code would look like this:

```
String randomString = plugin.getRandomStringFromList(plugin.getLocationList());

p.teleport(new Location(Bukkit.getWorld("world"),
  plugin.getConfig().getInt("locations." + randomString + ".x"), 
  plugin.getConfig().getInt("locations." + randomString + ".y"), 
  plugin.getConfig().getInt("locations." + randomString + ".z")));
```

Comment: Upvote yours because you reformat the line, still a lot of think happening in that unique line but at least, readable

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are randomizing "get location" on 3 different instance in the same line

What you could do is that you could save the results of the first instance and reuse it

```
var location = plugin.getRandomStringFromList(plugin.getLocationList());

p.teleport(new Location(Bukkit.getWorld("world"), 

plugin.getConfig().getInt("locations." + location + ".x"), 
plugin.getConfig().getInt("locations." + location + ".y"), 
plugin.getConfig().getInt("locations." + location + ".z")));
```